# What does the fromIntegral type here actually do?

Tags: haskell

I just want to clear my doubts on the **fromIntegral** type in Haskell.

The output for these 2 euclidean distance functions are the same, so what's the point of putting fromIntegral? Like they both give floating point values of the euclidean distances.

Also, for the type definition of my function distance2 which uses the fromIntegral type, why is it (Floating a1, Integral a2) and then => (a2, a2) -> (a2, a2) -> a1?
I just don't quite get the interpretation of it here.

```
distance2 :: (Floating a1, Integral a2) => (a2, a2) -> (a2, a2) -> a1
distance2 (x1, y1) (x2, y2) 
      = sqrt (fromIntegral ((x2-x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2))

distance3 :: Floating a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> a
distance3 (x1, y1) (x2, y2) 
      = sqrt ((x2-x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
```

Could someone please help with an explanation, thank you :)

Comment: `fromIntegral` is not a type; it's a function of type `(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`.

Comment: The output is not the same, try `distance2 (0,0) (9000,9011) - distance3 (0,0) (9000,9011) :: Float`.

Answer (score 3):

> The output for these 2 euclidean distance functions are the same, so what's the point of putting fromIntegral? Like they both give floating point values of the euclidean distances.

They both *give* floating point values, but they don't both *take* floating point values.

```
> distance3 (pi, 0) (0, 0)
3.141592653589793
> distance2 (pi, 0) (0, 0)
<interactive>:2:1: error:
    • Could not deduce (Integral a20) arising from a use of ‘distance2’
      from the context: Floating a1
        bound by the inferred type of it :: Floating a1 => a1
<snipped considerable additional error text>
```

> Also, for the type definition of my function distance2 which uses the fromIntegral type, why is it (Floating a1, Integral a2) and then => (a2, a2) -> (a2, a2) -> a1?

Your `distance2` function takes numbers, and returns numbers, but not the same type of numbers. The incoming numbers must be integer-like things, so that you can apply `fromIntegral` to them; but the outgoing numbers must be floating-point-like things, so that you can apply `sqrt` to them. For example, here are some monomorphic types that `distance2` can be specialized to:

```
(Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Double
(Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer) -> Double
(Word, Word) -> (Word, Word) -> Float
```

This English description is captured by creating two type variables, each with different constraints. An identical type for `distance2`, but with somewhat more human-readable variable names, might look like this:

```
(Floating float, Integral int) => (int, int) -> (int, int) -> float
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused like for the brackets around (Floating a1, Integral a2), does it mean like in my points that I've taken, (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), x1 is a float and y1 is an Integral? Similarly for points (x2,y2)? Sorry.

Comment: @LorenBeer No, not quite. It means that in the *type* that follows, `a1` is a `Floating` and `a2` is an `Integral`. Since the type of your points in `distance2` is `(a2, a2)` -- that is, both `a2` -- that means both the x and y coordinates must be `Integral`.

Answer (score 1):

`fromIntegral` is used to convert the value of type `Integral a => a` that your sum-of-squares produces into a value of type `Floating a => a` that `sqrt` expects.

`fromIntegral` has type `(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`. That means that, given a value of type `Integral a`, it will give you back a value of *any* type `b` that has a `Num` instance. Since `Floating` has `Num` as a superclass (by way of `Fractional`), that means `fromIntegral` can produce a value of type `Floating a => a`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two relevant typeclasses here:

- `Integral` is the typeclass for types representing a subset of integers

  - each `Integral` type has a function `toInteger` that converts its values to the arbitrary-length integer type `Integer`
- `Num` is the typeclass for numeric types that include integers as a subset

  - each `Num` type has a function `fromInteger` that converts arbitrary-length `Integer` values to values of that `Num` type

The prelude function `fromIntegral` is defined as:

```
fromIntegral = fromInteger . toInteger
```

It uses both of those functions to convert any `Integral` type to any `Num` type.

This is what lets your first function take *any* `Integral` type as input:  the input type is inferred through the sum-of-squared-differences expression as the input to `fromIntegral`, and selects `toInteger` from that type's instance of `Integral`, while the `Floating` output type is inferred through the `sqrt` function to demand it as a result from the `fromIntegral` call, and selects the `fromInteger` from the output type's `Num` instance.